# How to check if an element is also in another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Imagine a function:

```
def Intersects (x, list1, list2, list3):
    if x in list1 and x in list2 and x in list3: return True
    return False
```

There has to be a better way to do this but I can't figure it out. How can I do this? (performance is important)

**EDIT:** I've come across a related, however harder problem this time. This time I've got 3 unrelated integers and I need to test if they intersect too.

Like:

```
1, 2, 3 <-- elements to look for
if InAll ((1, 2, 3)) ...
```

but I am not looking for a tuple, instead I am looking for just integers. How do I unpack the tuple and do the same search?

Comment: I wouldn't call this function `Intersects`- it is checking to see if one item is in each of many lists.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. :) I'll use "inAll"

Comment: @TheConjuring: In the comments below you asked what does `O(1)` and `O(n)` mean. Roughly, it is a measure of how long it takes for an operation to complete, as a function of the size of the input. If an operation is `O(1)` then it takes a constant amount of time regardless of the size of input. If an operation is `O(n)` then it takes a amount of time that is proportional (linearly) with the size of the input. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and [this Python page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to be able to give it any number of lists (not just three), you might like:

```
def inAll(x, *lsts):
    return all((x in l) for l in lsts)
```

If you are checking memberships in these lists many times (on many `x`s, that is), you'll want to make each into a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) before you start looping through the `x`s.

From your most recent edit, it looks like you also want to be able to pass multiple items in `x`. Code for that would be:

```
def inAll(xs, *lsts):
    return all(all(x in l for x in xs) for l in lsts)
```

Comment: You can pass a generator expression to `all` so you can drop the brackets around your list comprehension.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the information and correction on my (deleted) post!

Comment: this wont work in the instance where it can either be a list or a scalar ... but yeah this is probably the best answer in terms of dynamic list length ...

Comment: @The Conjuring:  I must second the point that if you are testing membership multiple times converting your lists to sets is essential to a well performing solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def intersects(x,L1,L2,L3):
     if not isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):
            x = [x]
     return set(x).intersection(L1).intersection(L2).intersection(L3) == set(x)
```

should work for lots of stuff

```
>>> l1 = range(10)
>>> l2 = range(5,10)
>>> l3 = range(2,7)
>>> def intersects(x,L1,L2,L3):
...      if not isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):
...             x = [x]
...      return set(x).intersection(L1).intersection(L2).intersection(L3) == set(x)
...
>>> intersects(6,l1,l2,l3)
True
>>> intersects((5,6),l1,l2,l3)
True
>>> intersects((5,6,7),l1,l2,l3)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do something like this is to use the set...probably it will be more efficient even with the conversion time:

```
def InAll(element_list, *sets):
    #calculate the intersection between all the sets
    intersection = reduce( lambda i , j: i & j, sets )
    #check if every element is in the intersection
   return all( i in intersection for i in element_list )


sets = [ set(range(5)), set(range(10)) ]
InAll( [9], *sets )
#False

sets = [ set(range(5)), set(range(10)) ]
InAll( [1,3], *sets )
#True
```

It's better to convert the list into set beforehand, but it's easy to insert the conversion conde inside the function (but if you have a lot of these controls, keep a copy of the set)